# Slider on JavaScript after clicking on the left arrow if i take mouse out or click on the right arrow slider is not working

Tags: javascript, slider

Using a [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLF6r1R6EDw&t=2595s&list=LLVhDqMTkpfba4asrTTdydcA&index=15) a created a JavaScript slider on my [website](https://imirina.com/index.html) . In the tutorial a vlogger creates only a foward loop without creating a backward loop.

According to my idea, the slider works onload 4 sec interval when a user has mouseover loop stops. A user can control the slider by clicking to the arrows to the left and right and when takes mouseout the slider should restart sliding forward.

I have a problem when a user clicks on the left arrow  and takes mouseout the slider stops working and the same happens if a user after clicking on the left clicks on the right arrow.
It seems to me that after using Loop2, backward loop, it cannot get back to Loop, forward loop.
My code is [here](https://pastebin.com/dkXXaDpu) or

```js
var bannerStatus = 1;
var bannerTimer = 4000;
 
// slider starts working on load
window.onload = function() {
    bannerLoop();  
    var startBannerLoop = setInterval(function() {
    bannerLoop();
    }, bannerTimer);
    // on mouse over loop stops
    document.getElementById("main-banner").onmouseover = function() {
        console.log("Inside onmouseover function")
        clearInterval(startBannerLoop);
    },
    // on mouse out it restarts sliding to the right
    document.getElementById("main-banner").onmouseout = function() {
        startBannerLoop = setInterval(function() {
    bannerLoop();
    }, bannerTimer);
    }
    // on click on the left arrow on the slider it slides back
    document.getElementById("imgbanbtn-prev").onclick = function() {
        console.log("Inside bannerLoop2 function")
        bannerLoop2();
    }
    // on click on the right arrow on the slider it slides forward
    document.getElementById("imgbanbtn-next").onclick = function() {
        bannerLoop();
    }
}
 
// first loop to slide pictures to the right
function bannerLoop() {
    if (bannerStatus === 1) {
        console.log("insideBannerLoop")
        document.getElementById("language").style.opacity="0";
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("work").style.right="0px";
            document.getElementById("work").style.zIndex="4";
            document.getElementById("language").style.right="-350px";
            document.getElementById("language").style.zIndex="3";
            document.getElementById("yoga").style.right="350px";
            document.getElementById("yoga").style.zIndex="2";
            document.getElementById("travel").style.right="700px";
            document.getElementById("travel").style.zIndex="1";
        }, 500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("language").style.opacity="1";
        }, 1000);
       
        bannerStatus = 2;
    }
    else if (bannerStatus === 2) {
        document.getElementById("yoga").style.opacity="0";
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("language").style.right="0px";
            document.getElementById("language").style.zIndex="4";
            document.getElementById("yoga").style.right="-350px";
            document.getElementById("yoga").style.zIndex="3";
            document.getElementById("travel").style.right="350px";
            document.getElementById("travel").style.zIndex="2";
            document.getElementById("work").style.right="700px";
            document.getElementById("work").style.zIndex="1";
        }, 500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("yoga").style.opacity="1";
        }, 1000);
       
        bannerStatus = 3;
    }
    else if (bannerStatus === 3) {
        document.getElementById("travel").style.opacity="0";
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("yoga").style.right="0px";
            document.getElementById("yoga").style.zIndex="4";
            document.getElementById("travel").style.right="-350px";
            document.getElementById("travel").style.zIndex="3";
            document.getElementById("work").style.right="350px";
            document.getElementById("work").style.zIndex="2";
            document.getElementById("language").style.right="700px";
            document.getElementById("language").style.zIndex="1";
        }, 500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("travel").style.opacity="1";
        }, 1000);
       
        bannerStatus = 4;
    }
    else if (bannerStatus === 4) {
        document.getElementById("work").style.opacity="0";
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("travel").style.right="0px";
            document.getElementById("travel").style.zIndex="4";
            document.getElementById("work").style.right="-350px";
            document.getElementById("work").style.zIndex="3";
            document.getElementById("language").style.right="350px";
            document.getElementById("language").style.zIndex="2";
            document.getElementById("yoga").style.right="700px";
            document.getElementById("yoga").style.zIndex="1";
        }, 500);
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("work").style.opacity="1";
        }, 1000);
       
        bannerStatus = 1;
    }
}
// second loop to slide pictures to the left       
function bannerLoop2() {
    if (bannerStatus === 1) {
        console.log("insideBannerLoop")
        document.getElementById("travel").style.opacity="0";
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("work").style.left="0px";
            document.getElementById("work").style.zIndex="4";
            document.getElementById("travel").style.left="-350px";
            document.getElementById("travel").style.zIndex="3";
            document.getElementById("yoga").style.left="350px";
            document.getElementById("yoga").style.zIndex="2";
            document.getElementById("language").style.left="700px";
            document.getElementById("language").style.zIndex="1";
            }, 500);
            setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("travel").style.opacity="1";
            }, 1000);
       
            bannerStatus = 2;
            }
        else if (bannerStatus === 2) {
            document.getElementById("yoga").style.opacity="0";
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById("travel").style.left="0px";
                document.getElementById("travel").style.zIndex="4";
                document.getElementById("yoga").style.left="-350px";
                document.getElementById("yoga").style.zIndex="3";
                document.getElementById("language").style.left="350px";
                document.getElementById("language").style.zIndex="2";
                document.getElementById("work").style.left="700px";
                document.getElementById("work").style.zIndex="1";
                }, 500);
                setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById("yoga").style.opacity="1";
                }, 1000);
       
                bannerStatus = 3;
            }
        else if (bannerStatus === 3) {
            document.getElementById("language").style.opacity="0";
                setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById("yoga").style.left="0px";
                document.getElementById("yoga").style.zIndex="4";
                document.getElementById("language").style.left="-350px";
                document.getElementById("language").style.zIndex="3";
                document.getElementById("work").style.left="350px";
                document.getElementById("work").style.zIndex="2";
                document.getElementById("travel").style.left="700px";
                document.getElementById("travel").style.zIndex="1";
                }, 500);
                setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById("language").style.opacity="1";
                }, 1000);
       
                bannerStatus = 4;
            }
        else if (bannerStatus === 4) {
            document.getElementById("work").style.opacity="0";
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById("language").style.left="0px";
                document.getElementById("language").style.zIndex="4";
                document.getElementById("work").style.left="-350px";
                document.getElementById("work").style.zIndex="3";
                document.getElementById("travel").style.left="350px";
                document.getElementById("travel").style.zIndex="2";
                document.getElementById("yoga").style.left="700px";
                document.getElementById("yoga").style.zIndex="1";
                }, 500);
                setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById("work").style.opacity="1";
                }, 1000);
                bannerStatus = 1;
            }
}
```